How to optimize method with multiple query calls?
I have an event system in my app. Every time a user deletes/updates/creates and object a new event is created in the database with the info of the object and the type of event it is.
My Event model looks something like this:
class Event(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    event_type = enum.EnumField(ModelEventType)

In this model, model is the name of the object's model, and object_id is the ID of that object.
My app also has multiple access permissions: some objects are private to the user, while others are shared among teammates. Thus, I need to restrict events to only those that correspond to a user's access level. To fetch each user's events, I retrieve all objects the user has access to, obtain their IDs, and then fetch the events related to those objects.
I use a method like this to fetch the objects belonging to a user:
class Event(models.Model):
   ....

   @staticmethod
   def get_events_ids(request):
      object_ids = {}

      Object1 = apps.get_model("myapp", "Object1")
      Object2 = apps.get_model("myapp", "Object2")
      Object3 = apps.get_model("myapp", "Object3")
      Object4 = apps.get_model("myapp", "Object4")
      Object5 = apps.get_model("myapp", "Object5")

      objects1 = Object1.objects.filter(...)
      objects2 = Object2.objects.filter(...)
      objects3 = Object3.objects.filter(...)
      objects4 = Object4.objects.filter(...)
      objects5 = Object5.objects.filter(...)
        
      objects = {
            "Object1": objects1,
            "Object2": objects2,
            "Object3": objects3,
            "Object4": objects4,
            "Object5": objects5,
        }

       for key in objects.keys():
            object_ids[key] = list(objects[key].values_list("id", flat=True))

       return object_ids

I apply this approach to many more models. With this method, I get the IDs of each model and then filter events by model and ID:
event_objects = Event.get_events_ids()
events = []
# Get the events of each model
for key in event_objects.keys():
   ids = event_objects[key]
   events_list = qs.filter(object_id__in=ids, model=key)
   events.extend(list(events_list))
ids = [obj.uuid for obj in events]

filtered_events = qs.filter(uuid__in=ids)

The problem I'm facing is that this approach is slow and inefficient due to the large number of queries involved. Is there a way to perform a bulk fetch or something similar to improve response time? Any suggestions for optimizing this process would be greatly appreciated.

That seems like a strange design.  Usually, you would have a fixed set of events, users would be assigned permissions to those events, and objects could choose the events they want to send.  Adding a new object shouldn't require you to reassign events to all users.

if you want just pk, use filter and values_list.
def aa():
  a = model.objects.filter(a={})
  if user.permission == 1:
    a = a.objects.filter({permission query)
  if user.permiision == 2:
    ...

  return a.values_list('pk', flat=True)


